# Assume $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise independent events. Decide if $A\cap B$ and $B\cap D$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-limit-theorems, independence

Assume A,B,C,D, are pairwise independent events. Decide if $(A \cap B)$ and $(B \cap D)$ are independent events? Then repeat this assuming the four events are mutually independent.

Well, what I'm thinking is 
$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)
\\P(A \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(C)
\\P(A \cap D) = P(A) \cdot P(D)
\\P(B \cap C) = P(B) \cdot P(C)
$...and soo on
, which is what makes it pairwise independent, so assuming this is pairwise, 
then that means $(A \cap B)$ and $(B \cap D)$ are also independent
because

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)
\\P(B \cap D) = P(B) \cdot P(D)
$......this is correct to say they are independent??

then I dont understand to assume the 4 events are mutually exclusive?

does that mean

$P[(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap D)] = P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(D)$??

Which does not make them independent because of B?

I am not too sure. I am confused and clarification is much appreciated. Any help IS MUCH APPRECIATED TOO.

Comment: Pairwise independence does not automatically means mutual independence for more than two events.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $A\cap B$ and $\color{red}{C}\cap D$?

Answer (score 3):

In the title and the post, the question asked whether it is true that if $A$, $B$, and $D$ are pairwise independent, then $A\cap B$ and $B\cap D$ are also independent. (There is also a puzzling $C$ around that plays no role in the question.  But we have added a remark in case $C\cap D$ is intended, and not $B\cap D$.)

Not necessarily. Toss a fair coin twice. Let $A$ be the event the first toss is a head, let $D$ be the event the second toss is a head, and let $B$ be the event the two tosses are the same (both heads or both tails).

It is not hard to verify that $A$, $B$, and $D$ are pairwise independent.

However, if the event $A\cap B$ occurs, then for sure $B\cap D$ occurs. So $A\cap B$ and $B\cap D$ are not independent.

More formally, $\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{4}$, and $\Pr(B\cap D)=\frac{1}{4}$. But also $\Pr((A\cap B)\cap (B\cap D))=\frac{1}{4}$, and therefore
$$\Pr((A\cap B)\cap (B\cap D))\ne \Pr(A\cap B)\Pr(B\cap D),$$
so $A\cap B$ and $B\cap D$ are not independent.

**Remark:** Perhaps what is intended is to ask whether $A\cap B$ and $C\cap D$ are independent, given that $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise independent. Again, not necessarily.

Toss a fair coin $3$ times. Let $A$ be the event head on first, $B$ be the event head on second, $C$ the event head on third, and $D$ the event all tosses are the same. Again we have pairwise independence. The probability of $A\cap B$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, the probability of $C\cap D$ is $\frac{1}{8}$, and the probability of $(A\cap B)\cap (C\cap D)$ is $\frac{1}{8}$, so $A\cap B$ and $C\cap D$ are not independent.

If $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are **mutually independent**, then $A\cap B$ and $C\cap D$ are independent. For under mutual independence, we have
$\Pr((A\cap B)\cap (C\cap D))=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)\Pr(D)$.